# Eclipse Not Working With KitKat Update

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated my ADT to kitkat and it just stopped woking. When I click `File-->New--> Android Application Project`, it shows the following error.

An internal error occurred during: "Check Android SDK".

```
com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.getLocalSdk()Lcom/android/sdklib/repository/local/LocalSdk;
```

When I start the following error is shown on DDMS:

DDMS files not found: D:\Eclipse- Juno\eclipse\nullplatform-tools\adb.exe D:\Eclipse- Juno\eclipse\nulltools\traceview.bat

Can someone please help?
Given below are my PlugIn Version Details, if its of any use

```
Android DDMS                    22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
Android Developer Tools         22.2.1.v201309180102-833290
Android Development Tools           22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Hierarchy Viewer            22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Native Development Tools    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
Android Traceview                   22.3.0.v201310242005-887826    
PyDev for Eclipse                   3.4.1.201403181715
Pydev Mylyn Integration         0.4.0
Tracer for OpenGL ES            22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]Its because your ADT is older. Update ADT.
Help>Install New Software and 
update ADT.

Update your DDMS to 22.6.2.

Comment: But it doesn't show that ADT Update is available in Check for Updates option

Comment: Okay. Have you changed your SDK or Eclipse location?

Comment: Nope. I downloaded API 19 and updated the ADT plugIn (because it asked me to)

Comment: But your DDMS is showing 22.2.1
If you have updated all the available updates then it should be 22.6.2

Comment: Check the screen shot. It is showing 22.6.2 for all the Available Updates